# Number of divisiors of $n$ less than $m$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisor-sum, parity

I'm looking for a closed- or alternative-form of the function that counts the number of divisors of an integer $n$ that are less than some integer $m$ (interested in $m < n$, obviously):

$ \sigma_0(n,m) = \sum_{d|n,d<m} 1 $.

Or more generally:

$ \sigma_x(n,m) = \sum_{d|n,d<m} d^x $.

Or any important property of either (like parity).