# Number of bounded divisors of an integer

Tags: divisibility, divisor-sum

Given integers $n,t$, what is an upper bound for the number of integers dividing $n$ in the interval $\{1,\ldots,t\}$?

When $t=n$ this boils down to the classical divisor bound (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/) and the tight answer is $\exp(O(\log n / \log\log n))$. On the other hand, when $t <\log n / \log\log n$ the answer can be easily seen to be as high as t - the whole interval.

For the application in mind, I'm interested in the setting $t = poly(\log n)$. The proof for the classical divisor bound does not seem to be applicable in this bounded range variant.

I suspect this problem is well-known, but could not find a reference anywhere (a very similar question was asked here ([Number of divisiors of $n$ less than $m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927817/number-of-divisiors-of-n-less-than-m)) and on Tao's blog above, but got no replies.)

Thanks in advance!

Gil Cohen

Comment: This problem seems to be difficult, If I wanted to make it work: I will first find an equivalent to the integers divisible by all elements of $\{1,\cdots,t\}$ and then I can try to find an equivalent but this will be difficult

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I think I found some partial answer to the question I posed above. One can prove that for t = $\log^{c}{n}$, an upper bound for the number of integers dividing $n$ in the interval $\{1,\ldots,t\}$ is $O(t/{c^c})$.

I don't have a direct reference but one can get this result by looking at the the following paper by Chari et al. and references therein.

http://epubs.siam.org.ezproxy.weizmann.ac.il/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539793250330